# Cluster: sending messages from slave to master

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up a node.js cluster in which I'd like slave processes to send messages to the master so it keeps track of their progress. All the documentation I've read mentions passing messages from the master to the slaves and not the other way around, which makes me wonder if that is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between two different processes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213501/communicating-between-two-different-processes-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question has been raised before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213501/node-js-communicating-between-two-different-processes)

Ideally, you will fork a child process from your parent process, so that there are common interfaces for each.

You can then pass messages between processes using events.

Comment: sorry for the duplicate, didn't realize that process.send does actually send the message to the master.