# Node.js send event to another running application

Tags: node.js, process, communication

I'm looking for something to make my 2 running apps to communicate with each other. 
I have two apps - `main.js` and `events.js` and I want to send event from `events.js` to `main.js`. I don't even know what to google for that coz everything I can find seems a little bit outdated and I'm looking something different then redis. I found out I can use uuid to communicate between different node.js processes but I don't know how. Any information would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between two different processes in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213501/communicating-between-two-different-processes-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a message queue system similar to [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue).

This way you will be able to make your apps communicate to each other even if they are on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work without the redis backend you can skip the filesystem entirely and move to Sockets/TCP communication, which is one of the ways of getting around semaphores. This is a common method of low latency communication used by applications on the same machine or across the network. I have seen and used this method in games as well as desktop/server applications.

Depending on how far down the rabbit hole you want to go there are a number of useful guides about this. The Node.js TCP API is actually pretty great.

Ex.
https://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html

Comment: Now that I am looking this looks like a duplicate. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213501/communicating-between-two-different-processes-in-node-js